# Stuck on Some Javascript - Displaying Image on Mouseover of text

Tags: javascript, html, css

I'm trying to replicate the functionality of this page http://www.annedeckerarchitects.com/recognition/publications/ in a simpler way. The functionality I'm referring to is mousing over on something on the right and changing the image on the left.

What I have; https://jsfiddle.net/7j2zkndx/3/

html:

```
<img class="global-image" />
<div class="scrolling-list">
<ul>
    <li data-link="http://i.imgur.com/ne3L7hy.jpg">Link Test <a href="#">click for more</a></li>
    <li data-link="http://i.imgur.com/mwa1Wwl.jpg">Link Test 2 <a href="#">click for more</a></li>
</ul>
</div>
```

javascript;

```
var globalImage = $(".global-image").first();
$(".scrolling-list>li").each(function() {
    var list = this;
    var img = document.CreateElement("img");
    img.src = $(list).getAttribute("data-link");
    img.addEventListener("load", function() {
        list.addEventListener("mouseOver", function() {
            globalImage.src = $(list).getAttribute("data-link");
        });
    });
}();
```

css;

```
.scrolling-list {
    width: 600px;
    height: 600px;
    overflow: scroll;
}
.global-image. .scrolling-list {
    display: inline-block;
}
```

I'm honestly at a loss why it isn't working. It would be best to assume I'm a novice in JS.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`globalImage` is a jQuery collection. `globalImage.src` won't change the src attribute of the element. Use jQuery's attr function to set it. Also, you need to be more careful with your capitalization. `mouseOver` should be `mouseover`, `CreateElement` should be `createElement`.

`$(".scrolling-list>li")` only works if your `<ul>` is `<ul class="scrolling-list">`.

Lastly, you can have issues if you assign `img.src` before adding the `onload` event handler. If the image is cached, it might finish loading before there is a handler, which means that your code won't execute at all.

[Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/7j2zkndx/4/)

```
var globalImage = $(".global-image").first();
$(".scrolling-list>li").each(function() {
    var list = this;
    var img = document.createElement("img");

    img.addEventListener("load", function() {
        list.addEventListener("mouseover", function() {
            globalImage.attr("src", $(list).attr("data-link"));
        });
    });
    img.src = $(list).attr("data-link");
    console.log(img.src);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Another solution, if you want to bind :

HTML :

```
<img class="global-image" />
<div>
    <ul class="scrolling-list">
        <li data-link="https://i.imgur.com/ne3L7hy.jpg">Link Test <a href="#" class="aToBind">click for more</a></li>
        <li data-link="https://i.imgur.com/mwa1Wwl.jpg">Link Test 2 <a href="#" class="aToBind">click for more</a></li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

Javascript :

```
$("a.aToBind").mouseover(function(){
    let liParent = $(this).parent("li");
    $(".global-image").attr("src", $(liParent).attr("data-link"));
})
```

The class "aToBind" is only use to separate these "a" from other "a" in the rest of script.